# Python: Using a variable dynamically to call a Dictionary Key in a Class instance

Tags: python, function, class

I am trying to creating a function in class Student that searches for a dynamically created attribute. I cannot find a way to use the parameter of the **function export_rubric_inputs(self, rubric)** to call the dictionary key. Note that the attribute will be a dictionary created from the save_rubric_inputs function.

I have tried many different things, including using the getattr, but because it was a dictionary it would not work.

EDIT: I want to access the data that I had stored as a dictionary using the import function

Code:

```
#Example Dictionary
collector_card = {
  "name": "collector_card",
  1: "x",
  5: 3,
  7: "You are correct"
  }

*Metaclass: Makes a class iterable*
class IterRegistry(type):
  def __iter__(cls):
    return iter(cls._registry)

*Creates instances of students when imported from CSV File*
class Student(metaclass=IterRegistry):
  *Keeps Track of all instances of Class*
  _registry = []

 *Constructor*
  def __init__(self, name, student_id = 0):
    self._registry.append(self)
    self.student_id = student_id
    self.name = name

 *Takes inputs after created in Tkinter*
  def save_rubric_inputs(self, rubric):
    setattr(self, rubric["name"], rubric)  

  *What I am having trouble with*
  def export_rubric_inputs(self, rubric):
    self.rubric

# Creating a Single Instance for this example
dave = Student("Dave")
dave.save_rubric_inputs(collector_card)

dave.export_rubric_inputs(collector_card)
```

Comment: Do you want `export_rubric_inputs` to return the attribute set in `save_rubric_inputs`?

Comment: Please show how you would want to use your code, for example by including a code snippet together with the expected output of that snippet.

Comment: @SaedSayedAhmed Yes, exactly

Comment: What are the `*` for? Also, can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @AMC It was my first time asking a question on here, and the # were doing weird things. I did add a small example at the end. The answer below did work, I just don't understand why as it seems to reference part of the dictionary. I put the full comment below

Comment: _the # were doing weird things._ Huh, what weird things?

Comment: @AMC Making things into headers. I just played around with it. Looks like they must not have been in "the code" part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if the purpose to get what you set as an attribute, then you actually need to do the following in `export_rubric_inputs`:

```
getattr(self, rubric["name"])
```

If you want still want `self.rubric` to work, you will have to change the `setattr` line to `setattr(self, "rubric", rubric)` in `save_rubric_inputs`.

You current code creates the attribute as whatever value is in `rubric["name"]` but not as `rubric`, so there is no attribute called `rubric` (unless the value in `rubric["name"]` is `"rubric"`).

Comment: Thank-you; it did work though I am not sure why, as my understanding is that it is now referencing the "name" element inside the dictionary, but giving the entire dictionary? As for your last comment, yes, I have made a name element inside the input to make it so I could add it to the instance with the input function. Thanks again for your help

Comment: So, in `setattr` you are passing three things, the object you want to add an attribute to (`self` in your case), the name for that attribute (`rubric["name"]`), and the value (`rubric`). The name and the value do not have to relate. The *name of the value* doesn't affect the *name of the attribute*.

Comment: Ahh, thank-you. My brain had a bad moment there. Appreciate the help